# Function for recursive linebreak

Tags: vimscript, line-breaks

I am writing my .tex files in vim and have automatic linebreaks at 80 characters. I would like the linebreak to automatically perform a concatenation `J` if there is text below it, so that I don't get the following output:

```
This line gets line-broken. This line gets line-broken. This line gets
line-broken.
This line is short and could be concatenated.
```

If, after this concatenation, another linebreak is required, the function is called recursively.

Is there a simple method for doing this?

Comment: You can try `:help fo-a` but I don't think it will be what you really want, esp for TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to review the paragraph you are in is:

```
gqip
```

Where:

- `gq` reformat them according to `textwidth`
- `ip` current paragraph

If you want that to be made for all paragraph while they are edited a solution, as mentioned by @Ben, is to have `a` within `formatoptions`

```
setlocal formatoptions+=a
```

Comment: Wow, that works really well. How would I make that into an automatic script that gets called when the line gets too long?

Comment: isn't this `vipJgqq`? easier to type, IMO (edit: `gqip` should just work)

Comment: @ness_boy if you want that for every paragraph the solution of @Ben is good for you `setlocal fo+=a`. But there are probably some TeX paragraph that should not be reformated.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making the following macros that are working well for me:

```
function RecursiveLinebreak()
    call feedkeys("\gq")
    call feedkeys("\ip")
endfunction

autocmd FileType tex nmap <buffer> <C-A> :set fo+=a <CR>
autocmd FileType tex nmap <buffer> <C-S> :set fo-=a <CR>
autocmd FileType tex nmap <buffer> <C-J> :call RecursiveLinebreak() <CR>
```

These three commands perform the following tasks:

- Enable automatic paragraph re-shaping
- Disable automatic paragraph re-shaping
- Restructure the current paragraph the cursor is on

Keeping the accepted answer though, as it gives an easy way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Isn't your function equivalent to `normal! gqip`?